# Python DataFrame - apply different calculations due to a column's value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a question about selecting and applying functions in Python.

Say my DataFrame is:

```
Col 0   Col 1  Col 2  Col 3
Good      1      3      1
Good      2      2      1
Bad       0      1      1
```

I want to create another column 'result' based on the 'Col 0' value:

```
1. Col 1 - Col 2, if Col 0 == 'Good'
2. Col 3 - Col 2, if Col 0 == 'Bad'
```

I.e:

```
For the first row, result = 1-3 = -2
For the third row, result = 1-1 = 0
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks a lot !!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using 2 `loc` calls:

```
In [46]:

df.loc[df['Col0'] == 'Good', 'Result'] = df['Col1'] - df['Col2']
df.loc[df['Col0'] == 'Bad', 'Result'] = df['Col3'] - df['Col2']
df
Out[46]:
   Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
0  Good     1     3     1      -2
1  Good     2     2     1       0
2   Bad     0     1     1       0
```

Or `np.where`:

```
In [48]:

df['Result'] = np.where(df['Col0'] == 'Good', df['Col1'] - df['Col2'], df['Col3'] - df['Col2'])
df
Out[48]:
   Col0  Col1  Col2  Col3  Result
0  Good     1     3     1      -2
1  Good     2     2     1       0
2   Bad     0     1     1       0
```

The `np.where` version assumes that rows that are not 'Good' are 'Bad' or that you want to perform `df['Col3'] = df['Col2']` instead